# SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the connection has started

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, signalr

Trying to replicate an example I have encountered the problem that the connection is not made, when it comes to do it from a server to my computer, but when I work remotely if it works.

Links example

[link 1](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com.co/2013/09/ABetterWayOfUsingAspNetSignalRWithAngularJs.html)
[link 2](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com.co/2013/05/HookingUpAspNetSignalRWithAngularJS.html)

This is my code

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.value('$', $);

app.factory('signalRSvc', function ($, $rootScope) {
    return {
        proxy: null,
        initialize: function (acceptGreetCallback) {           

            //Getting the connection object
            connection = $.hubConnection('http://190.109.185.138:8016');         

            //Creating proxy
            this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('HelloWorldHub');

            //Starting connection
            connection.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
                alert("funciono");
            });

            connection.start({ jsonp: true }).fail(function () {
                alert("fallo");
            });

            //connection.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
            //    console.log("connection started!");
            //});  


            //Attaching a callback to handle acceptGreet client call
            this.proxy.on('acceptGreet', function (message) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    acceptGreetCallback(message);
                });
            });
        },
        sendRequest: function (callback) {
            //Invoking greetAll method defined in hub
            this.proxy.invoke('greetAll');
        }
    }
});

app.controller('SignalRAngularCtrl', function ($scope, signalRSvc) {

    $scope.text = "";

    $scope.greetAll = function () {
        signalRSvc.sendRequest();
    }

    updateGreetingMessage = function (text) {
        $scope.text = text;
    }

    signalRSvc.initialize(updateGreetingMessage);

});
```

Comment: have you got the solution?

Answer (score 5):

You should only have one `connection.start()` and not two. You need to add the `done()` and `fail()` into that call.

```
connection.start({ ... }).done(function() {...}).fail(function() {...})
```

Otherwise you'll try to start it twice. It might seem to work locally since there is no delay but in actual conditions the first won't finish before the second.

Comment: i try later, but when not use `jsonp: true`, show some errors.